# Automatically update formula results

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code:

```
Dim statdate As Long
    statdate = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("O2").Select
Range("O2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-9]<TODAY(),""Booked"",""Provisional Booking"")"
Range("O2").Copy Destination:=Range("O3:O" & statdate)

Dim canc As Long
    canc = ActiveSheet.Range("AH" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("AI2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=""Yes"",""Cancelled"",""Booked"")"
Range("AI2").Copy Destination:=Range("AI3:AI" & canc)
```

It should work out two statuses for two different fields - but it returns only "Booked" in column "O" and "Booked" in column "AH". This would be fine and usually I would search for an error but when I go back to the spreadsheet and highlight any of the cells in column "O" that should be "Provisional Booking" or cells in column "AH" that should be "Cancelled" to check individual formulas it changes to the correct outcome after I highlight the cell in "AH" and "F" respectively.

The formula is right but it won't update until I manually check each cell.

Saving and closing the document automatically updated all the fields that needed it. However I want to copy and paste values into a 3rd column with this macro and, as values, these won't be updated after I save the document.

Comment: Not exactly sure what might be causing it, but why not add a bit of code that selects every cells in the range? That should update them.

Comment: Apologies, it's not selecting the cell that updates it. It's selecting the cell and then selecting the specific cells that the code relates to within that cell that updates them. I tried selecting all but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using activeworksheet.calculate just before macro finishes

Comment: I didn't even know that this was an option - slotted it in just before transferring the values to the third column and it worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help!